# I want to prove that $R^+ = R$ if $R$ is transitive.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I want to prove that $R^+ = R$ if given $R$ is transitive.

I tried to prove it as follows:

$ R^+$

$ \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty R^n$

It reduces as : $ R^n = R$ for all $n\ge 1$

I use Induction here

for $n=1$ its trival as $R^1=R$

for $n=n+1$ so  $\qquad$   $R \circ R^n$

$ R \circ R$    $\qquad$  { I.H }

$R$    $\qquad$  { R is transitive }

Is my proof correct?

Comment: No, because $R\circ R$ need not be *equal* to $R$.

Comment: Ok so $R\circ R \subseteq R$, then how can I use it to prove

Comment: Come on, what does $R\circ R \subseteq R$ say? Can you show that $R^n \subseteq R$ for all $n\ge 1$?

Comment: Ok got it, this I can prove. Thanks!

Comment: You have $R^+$ on one line and $\cup_n R^n$ on the next. Is that the def'n of  $R^+$? And for binary relations $A,B $ does $x(Ao B)z$  mean  $\exists  y (x A y \land y B z)$ ? And your work has no words .

Comment: yes that is the definition of $R^+$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We don't necessarily have $R^n=R$ for a transitive relation in general. E.g. consider $<$ on $\{1,2,3,4\}$, here $R^4=\emptyset$.
2. As $R\subseteq R^+$, we only have to prove $\bigcup_{n\ge1}R^n\subseteq R$, that is, $R^n\subseteq R$ for all $n\ge 1$.
3. Yes, induction can work, and the hypothesis ($R$ being transitive) just translates to $R^2\subseteq R$.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: For $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$, if the only $(x,y)\in S^2$ for which $x R y$ are $(1,2)$ and $(3,4)$ then $R$ is transitive (vacuously) and $R^2=\phi\ne R$